# Is it possible to store a SQL Server table on the user's local hard drive?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database in a state own ms sql server. Writing user information in 
a table in the server means that the information is public. I would like to be able to 
write a table to the users hard drive - so the information is not on the server
and be able to access through a query in php with the state server in order to display charts. Is there a way to do this without having to install any type of software in the user machine if so, I would appreciate it if you could point me to the procedure that does this.

Comment: That's not possible without some sort of hackery.  Web pages can't write arbitrary files to users' drives without using plugins.  As to the issue of keeping user data private, most web apps manage this simply by enforcing their own application level access controls -- the idea that a user's data is private only if it exists on the user's personal harddrive is... unconventional, to say the least.

Comment: If you really do have data so sensitive that it can't possibly be stored in a central location, you may be interested in "HTML5 Client-side Storage".  However, I doubt your data is really that sensitive.  Even your bank is comfortable storing all of your data on their own central servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your real problem is of **data privacy** and not **where you store it**.  See this link:

[**How to: Encrypt a Column of Data**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx)

Without more info an exactly what you are doing, it is impossible to provide you with a more specific answer.

Comment: Encryption isn't necessarily required.  You can keep unencrypted data "private" simply by sending it only to the people who are supposed to be able to see it.

Comment: @Frank Farmer, I took from the question that the OP didn't want anyone with access to the table to see the data.  I would imagine that the application would control who "sees" the data.  The problem that the OP seems to be worried about is that **no one can control the "sa" user from looking at the data, so I say encrypt it.**

Answer (score 3):

Writing user information to a table on your SQL server does not make it 'public'. Your code will define who has access to it.

To answer your question:
You cannot create a database on the user's hard drive. Research cookies as that is your only option for storing information on the user's hard drive.

Comment: Cookies are no longer the only option, but they are the most widely-supported option.  HTML5 includes new client side storage, but many of the browsers currently in use don't support it.

Comment: if the OP is concerned with the actual owner of the server viewing the data (not via the application, but using SELECT, etc), then there is no way for you to "define who has access to it".  The "sa" user can see it, unless it is encrypted.

Comment: @KM I am having trouble understanding the question, but if this is the case you are correct. He should consider encrypting it, or, if the data is very sensitive it should be on a trusted server.

Comment: Hi thanks everyone for the answers, I did a very poor job explaining what this is for, is for a person to keep track of agrochemical application (type and concentration). Some concentrations might not be legal in a certain states. If the information for the user is stored in a state server it becomes state owned information which means there might be legal ramifications for the user. So the information should not available to the public nor the server administrator, only to the user.

Answer (score 0):

That truly is a function of the application that is actually hitting the database.  The whole point of SQL is that the data is stored on the Server.  The solution is to save some sort of XML encrypted or not on the local machine.